# iptables rule traverse order

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ufw

Here is partial output of my iptables:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   22866  3280283 ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   22866  3280283 ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3307   353252 ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3307   353252 ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3307   353252 ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3307   353252 ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0          

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2214   368749 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    7342  1051009 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    1884   204643 ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       2      120 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
```

Based on my understanding, the rules are matched form top to bottom. When a
packet is matched with a terminate action(e.g ACCEPT), it will stop. So, why
the ssh packet can reach rule 3 in Chain ufw-before-output and get droped?
Why it is not accepted by rule 1 in Chain ufw-before-output?

Comment: ufw generated iptables rule sets are difficult to read. Also you haven't listed the rules in a way that shows complete information as to interfaces involved and packet counters (I prefer `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L`).

Comment: @DougSmythies I have followed your suggestion and updated the output in the my question. Can you take a look and give me some suggestions plesase?

Comment: With the additional interface information, the answer to your questions becomes obvious. An outgoing packet to somewhere port 22, wouldn't be using the local interface. I'll write and actual answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule 1 in chain ufw-before-output has the additional condition of being only for the local interface (lo). The two packets that hit the ufw-user-output chain DROP rule would not have been destined for the local interface. They were also probably new tcp connection syn packets and therefore did not satisfy the RELATED,ESTABLISHED rule.